# Who are gratified when the sacrifices are performed by the demigods?

Tags: yajna, vedic-gods, sacrifice, demi-god

Who are gratified when the sacrifices/yajna are performed by the demigods? Like when humans make sacrifices they gratify demigod (like Indra, Agni, etc.).
I mean Indra is a god that had performed a hundred sacrifices. And also there is in scriptures that Brahma also had performed various sacrifices. So, for whom these sacrifices are performed by them.

Comment: It depends on what sacrifice is being performed and which deities are meant to be the recipients of the Havi. The mantras used while offering oblations make it clear for whom those particular Havi-s are meant. For example, if "idam indraya swaha; idama na mama" is chanted and Havi is offered then Indra will receive it and no other deities.

Comment: Yes it is true for us. But what about dieties themselves. They too perform sacrifices. For example if Indra dev is performing one. So who will be recipient then?

Comment: That will be known to Indra Dev. He must be performing a specific Yajna which is meant for a specific Deity. No general answer is there.

Comment: It’s interesting to see that we have the tag “demigod” on Hi SE even though we know many have complained about the word "demigod" on this website. ;)

Answer (score 2):

> Who are gratified when the sacrifices are performed by the demigods?

Themselves, and also Brahman.

The Madhu-Vidya is a meditation in the Upanishads where you meditate on the Devas. The question is, can the Devas meditate on themselves?

Kind of. They are actually meditating on Brahman within themselves:

> [Sri Bhashya](https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/sbe48/sbe48130.htm) of Ramanujacharya, Vedanta Sutras -
>
> For it is in [the Devas'] case also possible that their attainment of Brahman should be viewed as preceded by their attainment of Vasu-hood or Âditya-hood, in so far, namely, as they meditate on Brahman as abiding within themselves. They may be Vasus and Âdityas in the present age of the world, but at the same time be desirous of holding the same position in future ages also.

Answer (score 1):

Namaskar,

Satapatha brAhmaNa is one of the most important brAhmaNas that describe sacrifices. It gives a general principle which answers your question.

3.9.3.13-

> And when he offers that offering, he pours out (the ghee) towards that same sap of the sacrifice (in the water) and draws it to him. **And, indeed, he pleases those deities to whom he offers that offering**, and thus satisfied and pleased, they fit that sap of the sacrifice together for him.

> yaddhaivaitAmAhutiM juhoti etamevaitadyajnasya rasamabhiprastRRiNIte tamArunddhe
> yAbhya u chaivaitAM devatAbhya AhutiM juhoti tA evaitatprINAti tA asmai tRRiptAH prItA
> etaM yaj~nasya rasaM saMnamanti

When you read the relevant texts recited at a sacrifice from the shuklayajurvedA, you can see the deities whom it is offered to. These are the ones pleased by it. For example, in the [text for the agnihotra](https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/wyv/wyvbk03.htm) offerings are made to the Gods in general (verse 1), but also specifically to agnI and sUrya (verse 9), and then indra (verse 46) and rudra (verse 57).

My answer is that the other demigods that the sacrifice is offered to are gratified, so when [brahmA performed a sacrifice](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/the-skanda-purana/d/doc502159.html), this is what probably happened. I see no reason to believe that it is any different when a demigod performs the sacrifice, and brahmA is said to have followed all the vedic instructions exactly. It also seems plausible that a demigod could please himself by a sacrifice.